# Xpath how to get element by index AND attribute

Tags: xpath

Given this xml:

```
<mets:techMD ID="techMD014">
    <mets:mdWrap MDTYPE="PREMIS:OBJECT">
        <mets:xmlData>
            <premis:object
                    xsi:type="premis:file"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2
                    http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/v2/premis-v2-0.xsd">
                <premis:objectIdentifier>
                    <premis:objectIdentifierType
                     >filepath</premis:objectIdentifierType>
                    <premis:objectIdentifierValue
                     >bib1234_yyyymmdd_99_x_performance.xml</premis:objectIdentifierValue>
                </premis:objectIdentifier>
            </premis:object>
        </mets:xmlData>
    </mets:mdWrap>
</mets:techMD>
<mets:techMD ID="techMD015">
    <mets:mdWrap MDTYPE="PREMIS:OBJECT">
        <mets:xmlData>
            <premis:object
                    xsi:type="premis:representation"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="info:lc/xmlns/premis-v2
                    http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/v2/premis-v2-0.xsd">
                <premis:objectIdentifier>
                    <premis:objectIdentifierType
                     >local</premis:objectIdentifierType>
                    <premis:objectIdentifierValue
                     >bib1234_yyyymmdd_99_x</premis:objectIdentifierValue>
                </premis:objectIdentifier>
            </premis:object>
        </mets:xmlData>
    </mets:mdWrap>
</mets:techMD>
```

I would like to make a xpath query that takes both index and attribute into account. 
I.e can I combine these two into ONE query? (Its the stuff around the "object" element Im interested in):

```
//techMD/mdWrap[
   @MDTYPE=\'PREMIS:OBJECT\'
]/xmlData//object[1]/objectIdentifier/objectIdentifierValue

//techMD/mdWrap[
   @MDTYPE=\'PREMIS:OBJECT\'
]/xmlData//object[
   @xsi:type=\'premis:file\'
]/objectIdentifier/objectIdentifierValue
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace according part to:

```
object[@xsi:type='premis:file'][1]
```

if you want first `object` of those who have a given `xsi:type` value or

```
object[1][@xsi:type='premis:file']
```

if you want the first `object`, providing it has a given `xsi:type` value.

Comment: +1 Correct answer. Last predicate would be equal to `[position()=1 and @xsi:type='premis:file']`

Comment: @Alejandro. Yes. And in fact would be faster in some implementations.