# how to use xpath in attached screen shot

Tags: android, appium

I am unable to identify an element using xpath. Attaching the screen shot of the same. I want to identify the marked button and want click on it.  I have used the XPath expression:

```
("//android.widget.ScrollView[2]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1][@Text='CONTAINER_HEIGHT_BY_FORM_REFERENCE']")
```

Can some body help me out? Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: can some one please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the hierarchy view, your target LinearLayout is `clickable : false`.

Target instead the child `android.widget.Button`.

Additionally, there are some issues with:

```
"//android.widget.ScrollView[2]/android.widget.LinearLayout1[@Text='CONTAINER_HEIGHT_BY_FORM_REFERENCE']"
```

You would need `"...ew[2]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1][@text='CONT...CE']"`
However, most significant is the fact that your target LinearLayout does not have that text attribute. The child Button that the LinearLayout contains, one the other hand, should.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300840/xpath-how-to-get-element-by-index-and-attribute) for more details regarding index + attribute xpath notation.